# Autostarted application in windows 8 runs behind Metro

Tags: c#, .net-framework, windows-8

We have an application (digital signage media player) written in c# that auto start when the user log in. the application is started by a shortcut placed in the auto start folder. On windows 8 the application starts fine but it´s running behind the metro UI. When I switch to the desktop my application is running as intended.

I need to find a way to make my application switch to desktop when it´s starting. 
At the moment the only way for me to make sure my application is shown is by running it in 
it´s own desktop.

---

Yes. My application is running as topmost and it covers the normal desktop. I don´t know how the metro UI is shown, if it´s running in it´s own desktop or if it´s simply rendered above the normal desktop. I have tried the startup script "Send Desktop.scf" from http://www.7tutorials.com/how-boot-desktop-windows-8-skip-start-screen and it seems to work but I would like to control it directly from my own code.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `Form.TopMost = true;` property?

Comment: please register your account on [so] &[su] to regain control over your account

Comment: Why this this question has been migrated ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found one working solution that does what i want. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785054/minimizing-all-open-windows-in-c-sharp

By minimizing all windows the Metro UI hides as well. Im not sure this is the best solution but it seems to work.